# Add a button to the RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I want to add the RecyclerView item button.**

- Right now the button appears under `RecyclerView` , how can I get into RecyclerView.

**How do I add this button to the RecyclerView?**

Thank you for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="stechome.berkeylen.firebasedatabase.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />




</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npyUo.png)

Comment: In adapter xml show your button...

Comment: can you send me a screenshot how you want your UI should be? @bilgii1